# AttributeError: 'ConfigParser' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python

Такая проблема, я хочу закрыть файл с определенной кодировкой (UTF-16 LE). Но при закрытии файла ошибка.

```
config.encode('utf16')

with open('config.ini', 'w') as config_file:
    config.write(config_file)
```

ошибка:

```
AttributeError: 'ConfigParser' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Answer (score 0):

Так может кодировку нужно у файла, а не у конфига задать:

```
    with open('config.ini', 'w', encoding='utf-16-le') as config_file:
        config.write(config_file)
```